# On the space $C[a,b]$ of continuous functions on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

On the space $C[a,b]$ of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ 
prove that $du(f,g)=\sup|f(x)-g(x)|$ is a metric.
 Show that $f_{n}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$ if and only if $\lim \,du(f_{n}, f)=0$.

Comment: Use the definition!

Comment: What did you try, Where lies the problem?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a metric? It follows almost immediately; what part are you stuck on?

Comment: @anon271828 how to show the convergence?

Comment: @B11: What has you confused? The proof isn't hard, but maybe it isn't obvious. Where do you begin when trying to show this?

Comment: I learn metric spaces for one month. So I cannot apply my konwledge about convergence to metric spaces. So can you show at begining please? @anon271828

Answer (score 1):

$du:C[a,b]\times C[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ is well-defined because all $f\in C[a,b]$ are bounded (because $[a,b]$ is compact).

$|f(x)-g(x)|$ is pseudometric for each $x\in [a,b]$. So $du$ is a pseudometric too. if $du(f,g)=0$,then for each $x$, $|f(x)-g(x)|=0$. So $du$ is a metric.
Now
$$\lim du(f_n,f)=0$$
$$\iff(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists N\in \Bbb N)(\forall n>N)(\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|f(x)-g(x)|\le\epsilon)$$
$$\iff (\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists N\in \Bbb N)(\forall n>N)(\forall x\in [a,b])(|f(x)-g(x)|\le\epsilon)$$
which means $f_n\to f$ uniformly.